# How do I declare the signature of a function that must return one of its arguments? (in any language*)

Tags: scala, go, flowtype, type-systems

How does one express the signature for a `function` that **must** return an argument (or `this`) that it receives (is called on), <del>in TypeScript</del>? *Is there a programming language where this is possible?**

```js
// In TypeScript (or consider it pseudo-code)
class C {
  // EXAMPLE 1 – Not polymorphic
  chainable(x): this                 // MUST not only return some C,
  {}                                 // but the same instance it was called on
}
// EXAMPLE 2
function mutate<T>(a: T[], x): T[]   // MUST return a, not a new Array
{
  /* So that this doesn't compile */ return Array.from(a);
  /* But this is OK */               return a;
}
```

Conversely, how about a `function` that **must** return a new instance?

```js
// EXAMPLE 3
function slice<T>(a: T[], x, y): T[] // MUST return a new Array
```

#### ❌TypeScript

---

#### Go 2?

Would the following `contract` achieve the above?

```golang
contract referentiallyIdentical(f F, p P) {
  f(p) == p
  v := *p
}
type returnsSameIntSlice(type T, *[]int referentiallyIdentical) T
func main() {
  var mutate returnsSameIntSlice = func(a *[]int) *[]int {
    b := []int{2}
    /* Would this compile? */ return &b
    /* This should */         return a
  }
}
```

---

#### C++20?

Could the above be expressed as a C++ `concept`?

---

#### ✅Scala

---

*Originally, the question was about doing this in TypeScript, but since that isn't possible, I am curious if it is in another language.

*Feel free to remove a tag if that language's type system can't express this*

Comment: I am afraid that return will only match signature, it won't match the exact object.

Comment: I don't think what you're asking for is supported by TypeScript. You're defining the _type_ of the return value, not the _value_ itself. I'd love to be proven wrong.

Comment: This is usually something you’d check for in a test suite (something like `assertEquals(a, sortInPlace(a))`)

Comment: @MTCoster Yes, but it would be nice to express this as part of the type signature. Some built-in JavaScript methods also work like this

Comment: @Barry Is this not something that will be possible to express with C++20 `contract`s?

Comment: The question you're asking has nothing to do with Contracts - that's a language feature for preconditions and postconditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can - in Scala.

Class with a method returning `this.type`:

```
class C {
  var x = 0 

  /** Sets `x` to new value `i`, returns the same instance. */
  def with_x(i: Int): this.type = {
    x = i
    this   // must be `this`, can't be arbitrary `C`
  } 
}
```

In-place sort that guarantees to return exactly the same array (doesn't really sort anything here):

```
def sortInPlace[A: Ordered](arr: Array[A]): arr.type = {
  /* do fancy stuff with indices etc. */
  arr
}
```

If you attempt to return a different array,

```
def badSortInPlace(arr: Array[Int]): arr.type = Array(1, 2, 3) // won't compile
```

you'll get an error at compile time:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : Array[Int]
required: arr.type
      def badSortInPlace(arr: Array[Int]): arr.type = Array(1, 2, 3)
                                                           ^
```

This is called a [singleton type, and is explained in the spec](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/03-types.html#singleton-types).

Comment: @pete Francis Gagné has essentially ruled out Rust. I think you can rule out TypeScript for same reason - it also puts more emphasis on flow-sensitivity. Here, you wanted an special case of dependent types (where type depends on a value). But you can also kinda rule out pure functional languages (even those with dependent types), because in a pure functional language, a function returning exactly the same value would just be the identity function (because everything is immutable). You probably can write it in Agda, but it would be a bit dull (the identity function).

Answer (score 1):

In a language with parametric polymorphism, any function of the type

```
a → a
```

*must* be the identity function: since the function is polymorphic in `a`, it cannot possibly know anything about `a`, in particular, it cannot possibly know how to construct an `a`. Since it also doesn't take a world value or an `IO` monad or something equivalent, it cannot get a value from global state, a database, the network, storage, or the terminal. It also cannot drop the value, since it must return an `a`.

Ergo, the only thing it can do is to return the `a` that was passed in.

Comment: I don't think this is true. Take this OCaml example: `let notId r = ref (!r)`. But also, my question is not necessarily about pure functional languages

Comment: Also, my question is not about parametric polymorphism (`C.chainable` is not polymorphic and I didn't edit it...). Regardless, an `a ⇾ a` function can mutate the contents of its parameter, and then return it, assuming there are constraints on `a`, as there were in my example

Comment: @pete, in a statically typed functional language such as Haskell or Elm, an `a` *cannot* by mutated, because `a` represents any and all types. The function has zero information about it's nature, so all it can do is return it (mutation doesn't exist in these languages to begin with).

Comment: Ok, the answer says `"In a language with parametric polymorphism, any function of the type a → a must be the identity function"`. This is not true for most languages with parametric polymorphism. Example in C# (a language with parametric polymorphism): `class C<T> where T : new() { T fn(T a) { return new T(); } }`. In a language with no universal way to construct an instance of a given type, it is true. I didn't know this about Haskell & Elm.

Comment: @pete: In the C♯ example you posted, it works precisely because it is *not* parametric polymorphism, it is *bounded polymorphism*, in particular, you have the bound `new()` which restricts the allowed types to only those which have a zero-argument constructor. In other words, you can construct a new `T` because you have added an additional constraint to it to be constructible.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Ok I see. Even though one of my examples was polymorphic, what I meant my question to be about is: let's take a simple function `fun asc (t as (f, s)) = if f > s then (s, f) else (f, s)` (Standard ML syntax but I believe this should translate 1:1 to Haskell). Now, in the `else` branch this could just return `t`. Is it possible to express, in the function's signature, that it doesn't, and always returns a new tuple? (Or conversely for a function that always returns `t`... for a tuple that's not useful but for a record it would be, for example)